How do I review some common consequences of random oracle model (ROM)?
I want to get a really good sense of what ROM enables you to do. My main source of motivation is: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/549.pdf; as a probably incorrect / inaccurate summary, it says in ROM, you can make Fiat-Shamir incrementally provable.
I understand that, by the first principle, ROM allows you to do perfect hashing. The idea is that I want to have a more comprehensive review of what more that gives you (at least what most people doing research using ROM should know). And I also hope to understand some more granularity, as it seems you don't really need Fiat-Shamir to get incrementally provable non-interactive arguments in ROM, but I haven't spent enough time on it yet to find out why.
Some fundamental, key papers in ROM's literature or some good survey papers would be great. Thanks!

You may receive more answers by asking the same question on Cryptography Stack Exchange.
